# How to use threshold on CameraFrame android + openCV

Tags: android, opencv, image-processing

I try to use threshold in openCV sample code "ColorBlobDetection". But I found some error.

The error.

```
11-13 20:10:03.798  28032-30391/app.heng.opencv E/cv::error()﹕ OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (src.type() == CV_8UC1) in double cv::threshold(cv::InputArray, cv::OutputArray, double, double, int), file /home/reports/ci/slave_desktop/50-SDK/opencv/modules/imgproc/src/thresh.cpp, line 719
11-13 20:10:03.828  28032-30391/app.heng.opencv E/org.opencv.imgproc﹕ imgproc::threshold_10() caught cv::Exception: /home/reports/ci/slave_desktop/50-SDK/opencv/modules/imgproc/src/thresh.cpp:719: error: (-215) src.type() == CV_8UC1 in function double cv::threshold(cv::InputArray, cv::OutputArray, double, double, int)
11-13 20:10:03.858  28032-30391/app.heng.opencv E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-10693
CvException [org.opencv.core.CvException: cv::Exception: /home/reports/ci/slave_desktop/50-SDK/opencv/modules/imgproc/src/thresh.cpp:719: error: (-215) src.type() == CV_8UC1 in function double cv::threshold(cv::InputArray, cv::OutputArray, double, double, int)
]
        at org.opencv.imgproc.Imgproc.threshold_0(Native Method)
        at org.opencv.imgproc.Imgproc.threshold(Imgproc.java:9180)
        at app.heng.opencv.ColorBlobDetectionActivity.onCameraFrame(ColorBlobDetectionActivity.java:241)
        at org.opencv.android.CameraBridgeViewBase.deliverAndDrawFrame(CameraBridgeViewBase.java:387)
        at org.opencv.android.JavaCameraView$CameraWorker.run(JavaCameraView.java:328)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
```

Here sample picture before use threshold.
[image: Here sample picture before use threshold]

Here sample picture after use threshold that I want.
[image: Here sample picture after use threshold that I want]

The openCV sample code

```
public Mat onCameraFrame(CvCameraViewFrame inputFrame) {
    mRgba = inputFrame.rgba();  // mRbga = input frame with color
    MatOfPoint2f  approxCurve = new MatOfPoint2f();

    if (mIsColorSelected) {
        mDetector.process(mRgba);
        final List<MatOfPoint> contours = mDetector.getContours();  //contour info is ready in detector
        Log.e(TAG, "Contours count: " + contours.size());   

        Core.putText(mRgba, ""+contours.size(), new Point(mRgba.cols()/2, mRgba.rows()/2), 3, 1, new Scalar(255, 255, 255, 255), 2);

        //green contous and size=5
        Imgproc.drawContours(mRgba, contours, -1, new Scalar(0, 255, 0), 3);



        Imgproc.threshold(mRgba, mRgba, 0, 255, Imgproc.THRESH_OTSU);



        Mat colorLabel = mRgba.submat(4, 68, 4, 68);
        colorLabel.setTo(mBlobColorRgba);
        Mat spectrumLabel = mRgba.submat(4, 4 + mSpectrum.rows(), 70, 70 + mSpectrum.cols());
        mSpectrum.copyTo(spectrumLabel); 
    }

    return mRgba;
}
```

This is original source code [Here](https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/blob/master/samples/android/color-blob-detection/src/org/opencv/samples/colorblobdetect/ColorBlobDetectionActivity.java)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the [docs](http://docs.opencv.org/java/2.4.2/org/opencv/imgproc/Imgproc.html#threshold(org.opencv.core.Mat,%20org.opencv.core.Mat,%20double,%20double,%20int)) says:

> public static double threshold(Mat src,
>                                  Mat dst,
>                                  double thresh,
>                                  double maxval,
>                                  int type)
>
> Parameters:
>
> - src - Source array (single-channel, 8-bit or 32-bit
>     floating point).
> - dst - Destination array of the same size and type as
>     src.
> - thresh - Threshold value.
> - maxval - Maximum value to use with the THRESH_BINARY and THRESH_BINARY_INV thresholding types.
> - type -
>     Thresholding type (see the details below).

You need to convert `mRgba` to single-channel `Mat`.

[cvtColor](http://docs.opencv.org/java/2.4.9/org/opencv/imgproc/Imgproc.html#cvtColor(org.opencv.core.Mat,%20org.opencv.core.Mat,%20int,%20int)): `Imgproc.cvtColor(input, output, Imgproc.COLOR_BGRA2GRAY, 1);`

Comment: Sorry, and how to convert mRgba to single-channel Mat?

Comment: You can use `cvtColor` as I said in the updated answer. Use the appropriate `code` (`BGRA` or `RGBA` or other)

Comment: Imgproc.cvtColor(mRgba, mRgba, Imgproc.COLOR_BGRA2GRAY, 1);

Imgproc.threshold(mRgba, mRgba, 0, 255, Imgproc.THRESH_OTSU);